# Ionic Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I"m trying *ngFor on a typed Market[] variable, but for some reason it can't read the array properly. Ionic is complaining markets is not a array, but from my implementation it would appear it is. Help

Market def:

```
 export interface Market {
    id: string;
    symbol: string;
    base: string;
    quote: string;
    info: any;
    lot: number;
}
```

My Service call

```
  getMarketData(): Observable<Market[]> {
    let bittrex = new ccxt.poloniex();
    return Observable.fromPromise(bittrex.loadMarkets());
  }
```

My page setting the data

```
    markets: Market[] = [];
    async loadMarkets() {
      this.cryptoService.getMarketData().subscribe((data: Market[]) => {
      this.markets = data;
    })
  }
```

My template

```
<ion-list #scheduleList [hidden]="markets.length < 0">

<ion-item-group *ngFor="let market of markets">

  <ion-item-divider sticky>
    <ion-label>
      {{market}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
</ion-item-group>
```

What I don't understand is why I'm not getting back a array.

[image: error]

Comment: you seem to be missing `}` here: `{{market}`..not sure if it is related though

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it, but alas still the same issue

Comment: what do you want to show inside of <ion-label> ?

Comment: for now I don't care just want it read the array properly. I've tried without it with same issue

Comment: did you console log `data` in subscribe and verify if it is an array?

Comment: try {{market.id}} for example

Comment: I did a typeOf and it returned object. Which is why I'm confuse. I'm using Typescript and I'm returning a Market[] array...

Comment: {{market.id}} didn't work

Comment: what is output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));` ?

Comment: a json object. I'm confused according to typescript is should be a Market[] array.

Comment: so you need to see why your request is returning an object in place of an array..

Comment: Thanks, I likely need to do a map on Observable.fromPromise to ensure it's in a proper array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically my return object was not a true array. Even though Typescript was returning Market[] array . The result was a object of Market. The trick was.

```
   getMarketData(): Observable<Market[]> {
    let bittrex = new ccxt.poloniex();
    return Observable.fromPromise(bittrex.loadMarkets()).map(data => 
    Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `*ngIf` before `*ngFor`
try this

```
<div *ngIf="markets">
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let market of markets">

  <ion-item-divider sticky>
    <ion-label>
      {{market}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
</ion-item-group>
</div>
```

And check your response `data` instance is an `array | correct type`

```
this.markets=[]
if (data instanceof Array) {
      this.markets = data;
  }
```

Comment: These fixed the error. However nothing appears on the page (

Comment: Because your data format is not an array... Ngfor should accept array of data formats only... You should check with your data....